# Environment Analysis in Arkham Origins?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

In Arkham Origins, the Environment Analysis hasn't been doing much.  Is Environment Analysis only used for tagging datapacks and scanning the "A" symbol found around Gotham, or is there another use for it once you defeat a certain boss?

Comment: There are also commemorial plates spread all accross the city, behind which a piece of a journal is hidden. You'll need to scan those while in Detective Mode, but that's pretty much like scanning the Anarky symbols. There are also a few missions, where Batman tries to find out how someone died and who did it, using Environmental Analysis.

Comment: I don't have Origins, but if it's anything like Arkham City and Arkham Asylum, you also use Environment Analysis to solve Riddler's riddles.

Answer (score 2):

The **Environment Analysis** is used to interact with some game objects, mainly giving further commentary about them and marking them on the map.

- Anarchy's Symbols: Will acknowledge them as found and play comentary
- Cyrus Pinkney Plaques: Will acknowledge them as found and play comentary
- Datapacks: Place a marker on the map
- In Crime Scene Mode: Interact with clues, advance scene

That's basically what you and User Nolonar mentioned. Just summarized it in an answer.
I don't know of any further use. Feel free to edit this if you find more uses.

Answer (score -1):

as you say `Environment Analysis` use for these Issues:

1. Detect and finding Network Relays (when you near them you can see
   green wave)
2. Detect Datapacks
3. See enemy equipments
4. Solving crime scene
5. Little help to find enigma puzzle (or anything you name it)
6. vision in smoke area(when you drop smoke bomb)
7. Also Tagging anarchy Symbols

it's useless in fight with enemies or bosses

Comment: you're talking about *Detective Vision*, aren't you?

Comment: Yeah. That's Detective Vision, not Environment Analysis.